# É possível executar uma query (insert) e só depois verificar se é duplicado?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a ler um ficheiro XML e ao mesmo tempo insiro os registo na BD.

O meu código está assim:

```
foreach($itens as $item)
{
    ...
    if ( ! $stmt_insert_item->execute ( ) ) 
    {
    if ( $this->mysqli->errno == ER_DUP_ENTRY ) // se for uma entrada duplicada
        continue;
    else
        {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $this->mysqli->errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->error;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

O que me está a acontecer é que, sempre que tenho um duplicado, entra sempre no `else`, mas imprime o errno com a flag correta (1062) que é igual ao ER_DUP_ENTRY.

A minha pergunta é **há problema de executar e só depois verificar se é duplicado e avançar?** **Ou a conexão fecha depois do erro?**

Comment: Você utiliza storade procedure?

Comment: Por segurança trabalhe com Primary Keys ou Unique Keys.

Comment: @abfurlan não, é direto mesmo.

Comment: @Motta e trabalho, é mesmo esse o caso, dá erro da BD de chave duplicada...

Comment: @Jorge B. , a ideia é esta, dar erro.

Comment: @Motta eu sei, mas lê a minha pergunta a negrito, a conexão fecha depois do erro? É que eu não faço ideia porque mas este código `if ( $this->mysqli->errno == ER_DUP_ENTRY )` é sempre falso mesmo que errno = 1062, e eu não faço a menor ideia porque...

Comment: @Jorge B. não sei dizer.

Comment: Antes do `if` de comparação faz `var_dump($this->mysqli->errno);` para ver o tipo/valor que estás a receber... Pode dar-te alguma luz sobre o problema. O mesmo se aplica ao `ER_DUP_ENTRY`.

Comment: @Zuul Estão os dois com o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando ocorrem os erros em mysql disparam uma espécie de exceção, não fecha a conexão com o mysql, mas interrompe a instrução que está em execução, contudo em alguns casos esse comportamento pode ser modificado. Em procedures, trigger, functions é possível usar o [HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) para continuar a execução mesmo após um erro, ou ainda usar o [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) para gerar uma erro em casos específicos ou até mesmo alterar o erro. Mas para tratar o erro de chave duplicada durante o insert você também tem a opção de usar o [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) ou ainda realizar o tratamento dos dados na própria instrução de INSERT ensinando o mysql a tratar o dado duplicado através do comando ON [DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Ainda para tratamento de fahas você pode usar trabalhar com [transação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) e usar o commit e rollback.